# What are some introductions to classical statistics that emphasize unifying principles?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, frequentist

I'd like to know an introduction to classical statistics, that:

- Emphasizes connections and unifying principles (I checked [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166693/books-or-resources-for-learning-unified-view-of-classical-statistics) question and the links posted therein, but didn't find an introduction textbook)
- Concisely presents the solid basics of core techniques and concepts, like: linear regression, MLE, hypothesis test, confidence interval, unbiasedness, consistency, sufficiency, etc. (pretty much like the point 2 & 3 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290209/a-concise-guide-to-basic-statistics), but I am not a mathematician)
- At a level between a first and a second course (or a first course for an honors class?)
- And preferably, briefly introduces some modern computation-intensive techniques, maybe through code (like R).

For some background and books have looked at, see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/b1o35c/need_recommendation_of_an_introduction_book/) post.

Comment: @scortchi Sorry, maybe I have some misunderstanding, if so, please correct me. I don't think this is a duplicate question, although it might be too specific to be helpful to many others. The linked questions are quite general, except the first that is also linked by myself, which is an unanswered question.

Comment: It seems you're looking, mainly, for an introductory text on theoretical statistics (mathematical statistics, foundations of statistics, statistical inference). I can't see why those suggested in answers to the proposed duplicates don't fit the bill. Perhaps it would help to explain why, explicitly, for a particular, well known one. It's hard to understand what limitations are implied by "I'm not a mathematician" (measure theory too much? Basic calculus?) or "between a first and second course"). Sorry for my delay in responding.

Comment: @Scortchi Thanks for your reply. I added an answer to the first linked question. It may also clarify some points I did not make clear.